# How can I apply calculations at row level in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to predict a value in a dataframe based on two columns but adding the decimal residue from the previous row. This needs to happen only if store of current row it is the same as the previous one.

For example, I would want row 2 of this dataset to predict Forecast: 9 * Lag: 0.2 + residue(from row 1): 0.7 = 2.5

While row 3 should still calculate Forecast: 6 * Lag: 1.2 = 7.2 (because store code is no longer 100)

What would be the best approach to achive this? 
Many thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'store':100, 'Forecast':11, 'Lag':0.7}
       , {'store':100,'Forecast':9, 'Lag':0.2}
       , {'store':200,'Forecast':6, 'Lag':1.2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['predict']= df['Forecast'] * df['Lag']
df['residue']= df['predict'] - np.fix(df['predict'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to create columns with shifted values.

```
df['store_prev'] = df.store.shift(1)
df['lag_prev'] = df.lag.shift(1)

   store  forecast  lag  store_prev  lag_prev
0    100        11  0.7         NaN       NaN
1    100         9  0.2       100.0       0.7
2    200         6  1.2       100.0       0.2
```

Then you can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function to each row and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) temporary columns created before.

```
df['predict'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.forecast * row.lag + row.lag_prev
                         if row.store == row.store_prev
                         else row.forecast * row.lag, axis=1)
df.drop(columns=['store_prev', 'lag_prev'])

   store  forecast  lag  predict
0    100        11  0.7      7.7
1    100         9  0.2      2.5
2    200         6  1.2      7.2
```